# How to find documents by an array of IDs and be notified of the ones that did not match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As title said, I have an array of IDs which I want to `find`. I can totally fetch the documents from the array of IDs by:

```
model.find({_id: {$in: ids}});
```

However, there are cases that a document associated with an ID has been deleted. Hence, is it possible to get notified of the ID that **DID NOT MATCH** (aka **DELETED**)?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't array.find take a function ? How come you are passing a value ?

Comment: a mongodb operation

Comment: are you looking for a function that will be invoked when a document will be deleted?

Comment: I’m looking for a way to be aware of the elements that did not have any match. For example, I might pass in 10 IDs but only get 9 docs back, I want to find out which one didn’t return me the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think mongo has a way of returning unmatched results but you can use the results returned and compare with the ids list using a js utility like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference) i.e.

```
import { difference, map } from 'lodash'
// const { difference, map } = require('lodash')

(async () => {
    const results = await model.find({_id: {$in: ids}}).lean().exec()
    const deleted = difference(ids, map(results, '_id'))

    console.log(deleted)

})()
```

---

Another approach would be to use the aggregation framework where there is the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)** operator at your disposal. This can be applied in the following pipeline to get the deleted/unmatched doc ids:

```
const _ids = ids.map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id))
const pipeline = [
    { '$facet': {
        'matched': [
            { '$match': { '_id': { '$in': _ids } } },
        ]
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'deleted': {
           '$setDifference': [
               _ids, { '$map': {
                   'input': '$matched',
                   'as': 'el',
                   'in': '$$el._id'
               } }
           ]
        }
    } }       
]

model.aggregate(pipeline).exec((err, results) => {
    console.log(results)
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Looks like I'd have to resolve to using `lodash` after getting the result from `find`. I'll mark this as an answer when I solve my issue.